# Difference between – displayNameForKey:value: and - objectForKey: in NSLocale Class

Tags: ios, nslocale

Hi just a quick question what is the difference between – displayNameForKey:value: and - objectForKey: in NSLocale Class? I searched online but didn't get it. Thank you.

[Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
displayNameForKey:value:
Returns the display name for the given value.

- (NSString *)displayNameForKey:(id)key value:(id)value
Parameters
key
Specifies which of the locale property keys value is (see “Constants”),
value
A value for key.
Return Value
The display name for value.



objectForKey:
Returns the object corresponding to the specified key.

- (id)objectForKey:(id)key
Parameters
key
The key for which to return the corresponding value. For valid values of key, see “Constants.”
Return Value
The object corresponding to key.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use displayNameForKey:value: to get a label suitable for display based on the locale object you are calling. For instance:

```
NSLocale *french = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"] autorelease];
NSString *frenchName = [french displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"fr_FR"];

NSLocale *english = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
NSString *englishName = [english  displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"fr_FR"];

NSLog(@"French locale in French is called '%@'", frenchName);
NSLog(@"French locale in English is called '%@'", englishName);
```

will produce the output:

**French locale in French is called 'français (France)'

French locale in English is called 'French (France)'**

There are plenty of examples in the [NSLocale Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html).